# Problems constructing/editing a pedigree with kinship2 and optiSel

Tags: r

I have a data consisting of about 750 dogs that I want to assemble into a pedigree. The data includes ID, DADID, MOMID, SEX, Inbreeding Coefficients, and Coat Color. I have followed the guidelines for the proper pedigree data format, and the code guidelines provided in the kinship2 and optiSel packages, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have already created a sub-pedigree which displays a few individuals and their ancestors/predecessors. I can plot it with the function pedPlot from optiSel package, but the names of individuals overlap and, although the package says kinship 2 values can be used to change aesthetics, I haven't been able to use those values to change the branch length, text size, or even plot width. I am trying to use kinship2 plot.pedigree function instead, but am having even more trouble with this

```
library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(pedigree)
> library(kinship2)
> library(optiSel)
> library(gridExtra)
> library(ggplot2)
> library(ggthemes)
> View(pedigree)

> ajaxped<-subPed(pedigree, keep = c("Customs Ajax AAD"), prevGen = 
1,succGen = 2)
> ajaxped<-subPed(pedigree, keep = c("Customs Ajax AAD"), prevGen = 1, 
succGen = 2)
> pedplot(ajaxped)
> pedplot(ajaxped, cex = 0.5, width = 8)
> pedplot(ajaxped, cex = 0.5)
#these 2 are the same; the width doesn't change anything
> plot.pedigree(ajaxped,id= ajaxped$ID, Sire = ajaxped$Sire, Dame = 
 ajaxped$Dam, sex = ajaxped$Sex)
Error in matrix(0, nrow = n) : data is too long
> plot.pedigree(ajaxped)       
 Error in matrix(0, nrow = n) : data is too long
> plot.pedigree(pedigree, id = pedigree$ID)       
Error in plot.pedigree(pedigree, id = pedigree$ID) : Wrong length for id
```

[The plot created from pedPlot; ajaxped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrKCP.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you check out the [Igraph](https://igraph.org/r/) package, you can easily plot your pedigree